# Port 8080 just won't open on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I even disabled windows firewall but I still don't get the website (TFS website running on IIS7, Windows server 2008 R2 S1). It works locally.

I can open the standard page (port 80), so the rule that allows HTTP is working properly. I have checked online and they seem to suggest what I have already done (Add an inbound rule to allow port 8080).

Why isn't 8080 TCP traffic getting in the machine? It gives a timeout. Checked from multiple sources to make sure it's not my ISP.

netstat -aon shows System listening on 0.0.0.0:8080

[image]

Comment: Is there something attached to port 8080 in the server?

Comment: It is a fresh install, SQL server 2014, Team foundation server 15 RC2. 

How do I check if there is anything attached to the port that might make it time out? please note that it is running locally (localhost:8080), wouldn't it timeout if there is something attached as well?

Comment: can you navigate to localhost:8080 frmo the vm, does it actually show content?

Comment: Yes, it shows TFS error (can't show content), add /tfs and it shows standard TFS interface. Given that I turned off windows firewall. The only variable I can think off is azure inbound rules which should have been addressed by the image I posted

Comment: yeah, your NSG rules are correct. are you sure you are using a correct IP?

Comment: Yes sir, correct IP

Comment: maybe your local firewall blocks web-traffic to non standard HTTP(S) Ports of external IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue:

> I have opened the port using the windows firewall
>
> I have opened the port using the azure portal

It works on `localhost:8080` but it cannot be seen by the outside world.

I can get port 80 working just fine.

Perhaps `IIS` is interfering?

Comment: I figured my issue out - it was the incorrect security group on Azure that had the port opened.

Answer (score 1):

**To access any port from public ip client -**

Enable port in Azure firewall (if installed)

Enable Port in Network Security Group (add inbound rule) rule like 8080 -> 8080

Enable Port in Windows Firewall of VM (on azure) -- most important if port is other than 80 and 443. - e.g. 8080, 8090 etc..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Server Do the following :

1. Navigate To Windows Defender with Advanced Security
2. Add New Rule
3. Add port 8080 to it that is what is preventing it from being accessed from outside.